# Sugestão gerador SQL em sistema embarcado

Tags: sql, delphi

Tenho um sistema embarcado que fica no cliente, mas preciso desenvolver um gerador SQL que fique de livre acesso para os consultores e invisível para o cliente, ou seja, com uma tecla de atalho ele abra o gerador de SQL, mas por vias das dúvidas o cliente consegue abrir o gerador SQL pela tecla de atalho.

Queria uma sugestão do que poderia ser feito, com uma senha ou algo relacionado a isso.

Desde já agradeço ajuda de vocês!

Comment: O que seria esse gerador de SQL? é um Gerador mesmo, ou um terminal de consulta ?

Comment: É mais um terminal de consulta e alterações no banco de dados, que não fique visível para o cliente, mas pensando bem, vou fazer com senha.

Comment: Porque não instala um SGBD ? Sua base não tem senha ?

Comment: sim, mas esse sistema fica nos clientes do nosso cliente, por isso queria fazer algo como um gerador e não instalar a ide do banco de dados para poder fazer as alterações.

Comment: Cara, é bem complexo criar um programa assim, complexo no sentido de você garantir certas coisas. Qual componente de conexão você usa na sua aplicação principal ?

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma sugestão simples para ajudar a resolver a questão:

Em um novo form adicione um Memo, um Grid e 3 botôes (Consultar, Alterar e Limpar).
Um componente de conexão com o banco de dados (ADOConnection1, por exemplo), uma query (ADOQuery, por exemplo) e um DataSource.
Faça as alterações necessárias para acessar o seu banco de dados.

Nomes dos componentes usados no projeto:

Memo = memScript,
ADOQuery = qryExecutarSQL,
Botoes = btnConsultar, btnAlterar e btnLimpar.

Segue abaixo o código de cada componente:

```
procedure TfrmConsultaBancoDados.btnConsultarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Try
  with qryExecutarSQL do
  begin
     close;
     SQL :=  memScript.Lines;
     Open;
  end;
  Except
   ShowMessage('Erro ao tentar consultar Banco de Dados');
 end;  
end;


procedure TfrmConsultaBancoDados.btnAlterarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Try
  with qryExecutarSQL do
  begin
     close;
     SQL :=  memScript.Lines;
     ExecSQL;
  end;
  Except
    ShowMessage('Erro ao tentar Alterar Banco de Dados');
 end;
end;


procedure TfrmConsultaBancoDados.btnLimparClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memScript.Clear;
end;


procedure TfrmConsultaBancoDados.FormClose(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  qryExecutarSQL.Close;
end;
```